# Related Rates, my book does not help me

Tags: calculus

Assume that $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. Find $dx/dt$ given the other information.

$x^2−2xy−y^2=7$; $\frac{dy}{dt} = -1$ when $x=2$ and $y=-1$

I am trying to figure this problem out. My book does not give one example similar to it.

I'm assuming that the first step is to find the derivative, to which I get

$2x\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)-2\left[x(\frac{dy}{dt})+y(\frac{dx}{dt})\right]-2y\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = 0$

I'm not sure if this is correct, and I'm not sure what to do after this. Do I just plug in $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Be careful when differentiating using product rule.  Then, keep in mind the expression you want to evaluate.  Please use MathJax to format your question.  Consult this:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Calculus for Business, Economics, Life Sciences, and Social Sciences 

Barnett, Ziegler, Byleen 13th edition

Answer (score 1):

$$2x\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)-2\left[x(\frac{dy}{dt})+y(\frac{dx}{dt})\right]-2y\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = 0$$
You are almost there. It should be:
$$2x\left(\color{red}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\right)-2\left[x(\frac{dy}{dt})+y(\frac{dx}{dt})\right]-2y\left(\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dt}}\right) = 0$$
Next step is to use the informations you are given: $\dfrac {dy}{dt}=−1, x=2,  y=−1$ .And find $x'=\dfrac {dx}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-2xy-y^2=7$$
Now, differentiate the both side of the equation:

$$2x{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}-2y{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}-2x{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t}-2y{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t}=0$$

Rearranging this equation will give us:

$$-2(x+y){\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t}=-2(x-y){\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}$$

$${\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}={x+y\over x-y}{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t}$$

Now, you can plug $x,y,$ and $\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t$ to get $\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t$:

$$
{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}={2+(-1)\over 2-(-1)}(-1)=-{1\over3}
$$

To me, it seems more organized to solve for $\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t$ before plugging in values.

Comment: @Aryadeva Corrected, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct. Letting primes denote differentiation with respect to $t,$ we obtain $(x^2)'-2(xy)'-(y^2)'=7',$ which gives $2xx'-2(xy'+yx')-2yy'=0,$ which simplifies to become $$(2x-2y)x'-(2x+2y)y'=0.$$

Then given that $y',\,x$ and $y,$ you want to find $x'.$ Just plug away and solve the linear equation.